# Python FileNotFoundError :

Tags: python-3.x, import, module, package, filenotfounderror

I have the below structure

sample.py
pack/
-app.py
-test.json

### sample.py

```
from pack import app 

app.print_name()
```

### app.py

```
import json 

def print_name():
    with open(file=r"test.json",mode='r') as json_file :
        py_dict = json.load(json_file)
    print(py_dict["name"])

print_name()
```

### test.json

```
{
    "name" : "Rajkumar"
}
```

Now, if I just run => python app.py. I'm getting FileNotFoundError

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add absolute path to the test.json.

app.py:

```
import json 
import os

def print_name():
    dir_path = os.path.dirname(__file__)

    with open(f"{dir_path}/test.json", mode='r') as json_file:
        py_dict = json.load(json_file)
    print(py_dict["name"])
```